# For a patent application that is classified as simple, typically how many attorneys are assigned for such a case in a law firm?

Tags: patent-applications, attorney, lawyers

For a patent application that is classified as simple, typically how many attorneys are assigned for such a case in a law firm?

And if there are more than 1, why more than 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly all my patents were done in-house at my company and those were assigned to a single attorney per patent. I think this is the most common case at small firms too. In one case, a couple of my patents was out sourced to a large law firm. In that case an associate attorney drafted the specifications with the exception of the claims. A more senior attorney drafted the claims. I think the reason is that the senior attorney's experience is more needed with claim language. I believe this might be more common at large firms as the associate's billing rate is lower than a partner's and it would be very expensive to have the partner do the entire job.